# move site page from dev to production

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, data-view-web-part

I have seen a lot of resources online about something similar to my issue but nothing came to concrete help (content is old or not quite relevant) so I appreciate some help.

situation

- used SP designer 2013 to develop webpart site page
- Defined datasource to SQl server database connection
- Inserted dataview to the page based on SQL datasource

Now I want to move the page from dev to prod. I created the datasources on prod same as DEV

When I took the code of the pages on DEV and used on PRod , I had this error

Web Part Error: An error has occurred. Correlation ID: 9baf979c-1607-3081-07b4-a7577a8956bd.

Searching showed that this is expected because the webpart config is stored in content database and some Guids are involved here. I read somewhere that I can change the guid to name for DataFormWebPart  but that keyword doesn't even exist in the code (must be for legacy version)

So , how can , easily, move sitepage between sites on different servers? I do not want to redevelop things from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to migrate pages. You can package into a solution then deploy the solution in your target farm.

Another way: take a backup of the complete site collection and restore the site collection in the target farm.

Or you can use 3rd party tools. One is free from codeplex.

You can find the details here: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

There is a paid tool from ShareGate,
http://en.share-gate.com/blog/copy-sharepoint-page-layouts-and-publishing-pages

Comment: Thanks , I know about the SP Content Deployment Wizard but it needs to be installed on the server which I don't have access to. Will try the other options

Comment: Just tried ShareGate tool , excellent for the few pages I have. Webparts also came along, still testing it